# jQuery Burger Menu not working and not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find below my website's address:

https://www.economiseur-d-eau.fr

I have a problem with my website jQuery burger menu.
When I put some jQuery script, the menu was working.
But, it has some display problem.
So,I remove it and put another jQuery script.
Then, nothing was working.
Finally, I put back the first jQuery script, but now, it's not working at all. I mean it's not clickable.

Is there anyone who knows where is the issue and how to fix it?

Here is my current website [source code](https://view-source:https://www.economiseur-d-eau.fr/) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/site-template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-200254003-1"></script> 
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-200254003-1');
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->

    <title>Comment Choisir un Pommeau de Douche Économiseur d'Eau ? Le Guide d'Achat</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Vous voulez savoir comment choisir un pommeau de douche économiseur d'eau ? Voici notre guide d'achat !">

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->

<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
        <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="images/logo-economiseur-d-eau.webp" alt="Logo Économiseur d'Eau" width="272" height="38"></a> </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="mobile-view"><img src="svg/burger-menu.svg" alt="Menu hamburger Économiseur d'Eau" width="32" height="25"></div>
            <div class="desktop-view">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Guide d'Achat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Comparatif</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Top 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Marques</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main-content" -->

    <main>

      <div class="hero-content">

        <h1>COMMENT CHOISIR UN ÉCONOMISEUR D’EAU ? LE GUIDE D’ACHAT</h1>

        <hr>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor in cididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra</p>

      <a href="#" title="Comment choisir un pommeau de douche économiseur d'eau ? Le guide d'achat" class="btn-black">LIRE LA SUITE</a>      </div>

      <div class="image-grid">

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/magichome-pommeau-douche-anti-calcaire-economiseur-d-eau-haute-pression-filtre-a-trois-niveaux.webp" width="331" height="268" alt="MagicHome - Pommeau de douche économiseur d'eau - ionique haute pression filtre à 3 niveaux" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/innislink-douchette-a-main-salle-de-bain-7-couleurs-led-pommeau-douche-haute-pression-economiseur-d-eau-pulverisateur-double-filtre-antichlore.webp" alt="Innislink - Douchette à main - salle de bain - 7 couleurs led - pommeau de douche haute pression - pulvérisateur économie d'eau" width="331" height="268" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/omasi-pommeau-douche-haute-pression-anti-calcaire-filtrant-economiseur-d-eau-universelle-massage-3-modes.webp" alt="Omasi - Pommeau de douche haute pression anticalcaire filtrant économiseur d'eau universelle - massage 3 modes" width="331" height="268" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/acgam-pommeau-douche-economiseur-d-eau.webp" alt="Acgam - Pommeau de douche économiseur d'eau anticalcaire haute pression 3 modes - tuyau flexible" width="331" height="268" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/vadiv-pommeau-douche-anticalcaire-filtrant-3-modes-economie-d-eau-haute-pression-universelle.webp" alt="Vadiv - Pommeau de douche anticalcaire filtrant 3 modes économiseur d'eau haute pression universelle" width="331" height="268" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

        <div class="col col-lg float-left col-md col-xs"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/olliwon-pommeau-douche-haute-pression-acier-inoxydable-304-douchette-salle-de-bain-economie-d-eau-installation-facile.webp" alt="Olliwon - Pommeau de douche haute pression acier inoxydable 304 - douchette salle de bain économiseur d'eau" width="331" height="268" class="responsive-image"></a></div>

      </div>

    </main>

    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <footer>
      <div class="social-icons"><a href="mailto:contact@economiseur-d-eau.fr" target="_blank"><img src="images/social-facebook.webp" alt="Économiseur d'Eau Facebook" width="41" height="41" class="facebook-icon"><img src="images/social-twitter.webp" alt="Économiseur d'Eau Twitter" width="41" height="41" class="twitter-icon"><img src="images/social-mail.webp" alt="Économiseur d'Eau Email" width="41" height="41" class="email-icon"></a></div>
      <div class="copyright">Copyright © 2021 - Économiseur d’Eau - Tous droits réservés</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

And below is my website's CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*Global / Desktop View*/
header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.mobile-view {
  display: none;
}
.desktop-view ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.desktop-view ul li a {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
  font-family: josefin-slab;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #EAEAEA;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.hero-image {
  height: 450px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 0%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-image: url(images/economiseur-d-eau-hero-image-arriere-plan.webp);
}
main {
  min-height: 800px;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.social-icons {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.copyright {
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.facebook-icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.twitter-icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.email-icon {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.hero-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.guide-achat {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 32px;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
h1 {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: josefin-slab;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
hr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.btn-black {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.image-grid {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.col-lg {
  width: 31.3%;
}
.responsive-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.image-grid:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.text-white-description {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.text-red {
  color: #FF0004;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/*Tablet View*/
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
  }
.expand {
    display: block !important;
}

  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .hero-content {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .col-md {
    width: 48%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
}
/*Mobile View*/
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
  }
.expand {
    display: block!important;
}

  .hero-image {
    height: 350px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  .hero-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-content hr {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-content p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .col-xs {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
  }
  .social-icons {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .image-grid {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .facebook-icon {
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  .twitter-icon {
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  .email-icon {
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  .copyright {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

Also, you can check the jQuery scripts that I used as followed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mobile-menu').click(function(){
        $('.desktop-menu').toggleClass('expand');
    });
});
```

I linked a jQuery library to my source code as below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I also linked this script file called "scripts.js" to my source code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Finally, I didn't forget to apply the CSS class called `.expand` for my website tablet and mobile views, as you can see below:

```
/*Tablet View*/
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
  }
.expand {
    display: block !important;
}


/*Mobile View*/
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
  }
.expand {
    display: block!important;
}
```

I think I explained all the codes I have been doing.

Is there anyone who knows where is the issue and how to fix it?

I did put comments to my question, but I'm not sure you guys are able to see them. So, I write an anwser to my question again with the same comments. Hopefully, you'll see them and answer to them.

Below, are my previous comments:

"Indeed, I made a mistake with the CSS classes. So I replaced .desktop-menu and .mode-menu respectively by .desktop-view and .mode-view. And now, it works very well!

But, I just discovered a new problem. Indeed, when you click on the burger menu, the navigation elements break the design of the logo, the menu and the image under the menu. Do you know what the error is in my CSS code or my HTML code, or in my jQuery code? Could you please help me to fix this issue?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing classes `mobile-menu` and `desktop-menu` in your `js/scripts.js` but those classes don't exist in the HTML (they are `mobile-view` and `desktop-view`).

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake with the CSS classes.

So I replaced `.desktop-menu` and `.mode-menu` respectively by `.desktop-view` and `.mode-view`.

And now, it works very well!

Comment: But, I just discovered a new problem.

Indeed, when you click on the burger menu, the navigation elements break the design of the logo, the menu and the image under the menu.

Do you know what the error is in my CSS code or my HTML code, or in my jQuery code?

Could you please help me to fix this issue?